# How to use click event work in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting JSON data in my page, and I want to include "like" and "dislike" options to the buttons with a click event using the following code.

But I am not able to get the result. I'm not sure of how to loop the array.

```
//code for like and dislike buttons

$scope.li = function(ep1){
                    ep1.cue.episode.ratings.loved = 
                    (ep1.cue.episode.ratings.loved) + 1;
                    if ((ep1.cue.episode.ratings.hated) > 0)
                        ep1.cue.episode.ratings.hated = 
                        (ep1.cue.episode.ratings.hated) - 1;
                    ep1.liked = true;
                    ep1.disliked = false;
                };
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you receive the JSON data?  And explain what you mean by "not able to get the result?"  And show what array it is you're not able to loop through?

Comment: I don't see that code anywhere in your question.

Comment: I'm confused; are you suggesting when you receive the same data structure that you have in your plunker by some other means, that you aren't able to run that code against it?

Comment: ok I actually looked a bit more closely, the two samples aren't related in any way.  I don't see the code in this page in either sample, and you aren't illustrating what isn't working at all.

Comment: yes, but in your first sample, YOU HAVE NO BUTTONS!  You also do not have the code you are "not able to make work" in the project at all, so it's not possible to know why it works or does not work.  are you asking us to integrate one into the other for you?

Comment: sorry but in the code I'm seeing, they are in `<span>` elements.

Comment: where is this data coming from? are you in control of this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with the code which are both easy to solve.

1. Your button is trying to pass `episod` which is not a variable that is defined on the object.  try instead: `ng-click="likeme(tvshow.episode)"`
2. your receiving function is searching through a tree for an episode but not being passed the tree, it's already been supplied the episode.  so, instead of `parseInt(episod.tvshow.episode.ratings.loved)`, try `parseInt(episod.ratings.loved)`

**EDIT**

I forked your code [here][1].  Note the changes to the function, and to the HTML.  Passing the episode to the function, and inside the function, operating on the episode only.

Comment: the function declaration is ok, it's taking an episode and storing it in the `episod` variable.  it's the calculations in the function that don't need the extra levels

Comment: also, you might want to be careful with the misspellings of the variable name.

Comment: which part doesn't make sense? this is a pretty basic JavaScript concept, and I described what's wrong the best I could without doing your work for you.

Comment: yes it's working great. thank u very much sir. salute to ur understanding and knowledge.

Comment: if u dont mind pls remove ur forked code. thank u.